# File seperation on a website (in multi man projects)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a site that has the following characterics:

- Pages are being loaded inline through AJAX.
- CSS, HTML, JavaScript and PHP are all seperated to facilitate working with multiple people on a project.

Now I am making a `<select>` tag that loads dynamically from a database. Only I am experiencing a visual delay, my relevant pages are:

HTML, `content/sellmods.php`:

```
<h2>Sell mods</h2><br>
<form name="sellmods" method="post" action="sellmods">
<table class="accdet">
    <tr class="inputcontainer">
        <td class="label">Mod:</td>
        <td class="input"><select name="mod"></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>    
</table>
</form>
```

Relevant JavaScript from my own `framework.js`:

```
function preprocess(form) {
    $(form).find("select").each(function() {
        var select = $(this);
        callService({
            name: "select_" + $(this).attr("name"),
            data: { },
            success: function(json) {
                $(json).each(function() {
                    var html = "";
                    $(this.options).each(function() {
                        html += "<option value='" + this.id + "'>" + this.value + "</option>";
                    });
                    $(select).append(html);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

PHP backend, `select_mod.php`:

```
include_once("../content/includes/connect.php");
include_once("_functions.php");

checkAuthorization();

try {
    $result = $dbh->query("SELECT modId, name FROM mods ORDER BY name ASC");
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    error($ex);
}

$options = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $options[] = array(
        "id" => $row->modId,
        "value" => $row->name
    );
}

echo json_encode(array(
    "options" => $options
));

$dbh->close();
```

How the page gets loaded, once you click on a link for example:

```
function loadPage(dataUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "content/" + dataUrl + ".php",
        success: function(html) {
            setContent(html, dataUrl);
        },
        error: function(html, message) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "content/notfound.php",
                success: function(html) {
                    setContent(html, "notfound");
                },
                error: function(html, message) {
                    finalError(message);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function setContent(html, url) {
    html = $.parseHTML(html);
    $("#pagemain").html(html);
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
        preprocess($(this));
    });
    setNavTitle(url);
    //only if you actually load a different page
    if (currentFilename() !== url) {
        window.history.pushState({
            "url": url
        }, "", url);
    }
    //cannot unload old js
    //load new js
    if (typeof loadedScripts[url] === 'undefined') {
        $.getScript("javascript/" + url + ".js", function() {
            $("#pagemain").trigger("pageload");
            loadedScripts[url] = 1;
        });
    }
    else {
        $("#pagemain").trigger("pageload");
    }
    fireInputs();
}
```

I understand that the delay happens because of this:

1. I trigger `loadPage("sellmods")`.
2. An AJAX call is done to fetch the page, some small delay (40ms for example), then content is put on the website.
3. Then it starts to `preprocess` all forms, resulting in an AJAX call for `services/select_mods.php`.
4. After it is done (about 40ms again), the website gets updated.

This results in a noticable 40ms delay (could be sometimes bigger depending on server load), how would you tackle this problem to make it visually least annoying?

The user now gets to see an empty `<select>` tag, and then suddenly it starts to fill with data. This is not only an issue for `<select>` though, other data also gets dynamically post-loaded like this.

Keep in mind that I want to keep the HTML and the PHP seperated, any other solutions for that design principle are also welcome.

I hope the question was clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Usually a loading sign is accepted by the users. So you could display one until the last part of your ajax page is loaded. You could for instance have a registry, that contains all ajax calls to do. As they load each success event removes its ajax from the registry; if there is no more stuff to load, display the content to the user. Hope, that makes sense...